# Split text strings in a column with varying character sizes into (9) columns

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am attempting to create a summary sheet by combining multiple workbooks. In all workbooks, I'm only interested in the first column(sample name). The naming convention of these samples is identical and I have to break it into 9 columns. The challenge is that the different components have character size. I am trying to split column 1 (see picture) into the subsequent columns (especially splitting mass & kit highlighted in red and blue in the picture). Below is my code:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Enabling multiple files select
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.Filters.Clear

'Only Excel files can be selected
.Filters.Add "Excel Files", ext

If .Show = True Then
    For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        'Opening selected file
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)
        'etc do other things with it
        wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        Set wbS = ActiveWorkbook
        Set shS = ActiveSheet
        totS = shS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'insert new columns
         Columns("B:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Columns("B:J").ColumnWidth = 8.43
        [B1:L1] = [{"Project code", "Contributors", "Ratio", "TrueNOC", "DNA mass", "Kit", "Q Index", "Injection time", "Instrument""Source","Folder path"}]
        
    For j = 2 To totS
        str = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Kit = Right(Cells(i, 6), 2)
        Cells(j, 2) = Mid(str, 5, 9)
        Cells(j, 3) = "=MID(RC[-2],FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(RC[-2],""-"",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(RC[-2],""-"",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(RC[-2],""-"",CHAR(1),2))-1)"
        Cells(j, 4) = "=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-3],""-"",REPT("" "",LEN(RC[-3]))),(3)*LEN(RC[-3])-1,LEN(RC[-3])))"
        Cells(j, 5) = "=LEN(RC[-2])+1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-2],""_"",""""))"
        Cells(j, 6) = "=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-5],""-"",REPT("" "",LEN(RC[-5]))),(5)*LEN(RC[-5])-3,LEN(RC[-5])))"
        Cells(j, 7) = Kit
        Cells(j, 8) = "=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-7],""-"",REPT(""-"",4)),MAX(1,FIND(""Q"",SUBSTITUTE(RC[-7],""-"",REPT(""-"",4)))),4))"
        Cells(j, 9) = "=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-8],""."",REPT("" "",LEN(RC[-8]))),(2+1)*LEN(RC[-8])+1,LEN(RC[-8])))"
        Cells(j, 10) = Right(str, 3)
        
     Next j
                     
         'copy paste from each workbook to master creating a new sheet each time
            With wbM
                Set shM = wbM.Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(Sheets.Count))
         End With
                     shS.range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(totS, 13)).Copy Destination:=shM.Cells(totM + 1, 1)
                
         wbS.Close savechanges:=False
    Next i
End If

End With
```

Comment: Maybe you could start looking into regular expressions. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/NyuotW/1) I took a few samples of your data and grouped all the relevant information based on your screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from JvdV, I've elaborated a UDF solution that uses VBscript regexes:

```
Function fetchRegex(text As String, part As Integer) As String
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    ' set up re with desired pattern, extended JvdV's regex to include other sample rows
    re.Pattern = "^.*?_(.*?-[\d\w]+)(?:-(\d+(?:_\d+)+))?(?:-(\d(?:;\d)+))?(?:-\w+(?=-))?-([\d.]+)(?:K\d+-)?(\w+)(?:-(Q[A-Z\d.]+))?(?:_\d+)?\.(\d+sec)\.(.*)$"
    ' need this to return ALL matches
    re.Global = False
    ' ignore case
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    ' execute re against input text, returning matches in match objects array mo
    Set mo = re.Execute(text)
    ' we might not get any match...
    On Error Resume Next
    fetchRegex = mo(0).submatches(part)
End Function
```

The function can be incorporated into the above example like that (replacing the cell assignments):

```
        Cells(j, 2) = "=LEFT(fetchRegex(RC[-1],0),9)"
        Cells(j, 3) = "=fetchRegex(RC[-2],1)"
        Cells(j, 4) = "=fetchRegex(RC[-3],2)"
        Cells(j, 5) = "=LEN(RC[-2])+1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-2],""_"",""""))"
        Cells(j, 6) = "=fetchRegex(RC[-5],3)"
        Cells(j, 7) = "=fetchRegex(RC[-6],4)"
        Cells(j, 8) = "=fetchRegex(RC[-7],5)"
        Cells(j, 9) = "=fetchRegex(RC[-8],6)"
        Cells(j, 10) = "=fetchRegex(RC[-9],7)"
```

However, to really understand the working of the regex pattern, I strongly suggest to learn the basics of [vbscript regexes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html), [pattern matching and capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), [character classes in matching](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), etc.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Only a few adjustments that I can make manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to contribute with another way to do it I worked with this data in Power Query. Currently, Power Query (PQ) helps us a lot in data processing. If several Workbooks are used, this tool allows the reading of all of them at once and makes the conformation of the data read in a single table.
Below is de M code. Put it on the text area of the Advanced Editor (PQ>Home tab>Advanced Editor). Important: On the Excel front-end insert a table on input cells range and name it as "Table1". This is the expected name to work within PQ. (The intermediate names used here are long but do not affect the final result). More info about PQ (among others on www): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Splitting Column By Position" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Sample ID", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 4}, false), {"Sample ID.1", "Sample ID.2"}),
    #"Splitting Column By Position1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Splitting Column By Position", "Sample ID.2", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 9}, false), {"Sample ID.2.1", "Sample ID.2.2"}),
    #"Splitting Column By Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Splitting Column By Position1", "Sample ID.2.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"-"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Sample ID.2.2.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Splitting Column By Delimiter",{{"Sample ID.2.2.1", type text}, {"Sample ID.2.2.2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Sample ID.2.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2"}),
    #"Splitting Column By Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Sample ID.2.2.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"."}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.2"}),
    #"Splitting Column By Delimiter2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Splitting Column By Delimiter1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"."}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.2"}),
    #"Splitting Column By Delimiter3" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Splitting Column By Delimiter2", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"-"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.2"}),
    #"Splitting Column By Delimiter4" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Splitting Column By Delimiter3", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"_"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.2.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.2.2"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Splitting Column By Delimiter4",{"Sample ID.2.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.2.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.2", "Sample ID.2.2.2.2"}),
    #"Splitting Column By Delimiter5" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"-"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Splitting Column By Delimiter5",{{"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1", type text}, {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2", type text}, {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.2.1", type text}, {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.2", type text}, {"Sample ID.2.2.2.2", type text}}),
    #"Splitting Column By Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"0".."9"}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c)), {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.2", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.3", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.4"}),
    #"Splitting Column By Delimiter6" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Splitting Column By Character Transition", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.2", "Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.3"}),
    #"Changed Type by Local" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Splitting Column By Delimiter6", {{"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.2", type number}}, "en-US"),
    #"Changed Type 2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type by Local",{{"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.1", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Modeling Mass" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type 2", "Personalizar", each [Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.1]+(if[Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.2]<>Error.Record then [Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.2] else 0)),
    #"Modeling Mass1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Modeling Mass", "Personalizar.1", each try ([Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.1]+[Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.2]) catch()=> [Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.1]),
    #"Modeling Contributors" = Table.AddColumn(#"Modeling Mass1", "Personalizar.7", each if Text.Contains([Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1], "_") then [Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1] else null),
    #"Modeling Kit" = Table.AddColumn(#"Modeling Contributors", "Personalizar.2", each if[Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.4]<>null then [Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.3]&[Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.4] else [Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.2.3]),
    #"Modeling Q Index" = Table.AddColumn(#"Modeling Kit", "Personalizar.3", each if Text.StartsWith([Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.2.1], "Q") then [Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.2.1] else null),
    #"Computing TrueNOC" = Table.AddColumn(#"Modeling Q Index", "Personalizar.4", each Text.Length([Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1])-Text.Length(Text.Replace([Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1],"_",""))+1),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Computing TrueNOC",{{"Sample ID.2.1", "Project code"}, {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1", "Contributors"}, {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.2", "Ratio"}, {"Personalizar.4", "TrueNOC"}, {"Personalizar.1", "Mass"}, {"Personalizar.2", "Kit"}, {"Personalizar.3", "Q Index"}, {"Sample ID.2.2.2.1.2", "Time"}, {"Sample ID.2.2.2.2", "Instrumentation"}}),
    #"Modeling Kit, part 2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Personalizar.1", each if [Kit] = null then [Sample ID.2.2.2.1.1.2.1] else if [Kit] <> null then [Kit] else null),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Modeling Kit, part 2",{{"Kit", "Kit_old"}, {"Personalizar.1", "Kit"},{"Contributors", "Contributors_old"}, {"Personalizar.7", "Contributors"}}),
    FinalLayOutRemovingOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1",{"Project code", "Contributors", "Ratio", "TrueNOC", "Mass", "Kit", "Q Index", "Time", "Instrumentation"})
in
    FinalLayOutRemovingOtherColumns
```